# solving a Diophantine equation $17+2^m=n^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the method to solve $$17+2^m=n^2$$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$. I tried using modular arithmetic which seems did not help.

Comment: Are you sure this equation has integer roots ?? I doesn't appear so

Comment: @JEEAspirant note that $(m,n)=(5,7)$ is a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint: Take $m$ odd/even like below
$$(1): \ m=2k \to 17+2^{2k}=n^2\\17=n^2-2^{2k}\\17=17*1 \to \\17*1=(n-2^k)(n+2^k)\\\begin{cases}n+2^k=17 \\n-2^k=1\end{cases}$$ for the odd $m $
$$(2):   \  17+2^{2k+1}=n^2\\2^{2k+1}+1=n^2-16\\2^{2k+1}+1\underbrace{\equiv}_{3} 0$$ so RHS must be multiple of $3$ or $$n^2-16 \underbrace{\equiv}_{3} 0$$

Comment: FWIW I don't think this hint is helpful. $m$ odd is the hard case, which you seem to be sweeping under the rug. There are solutions of $ m = 3, 5, 9$. $\quad$ So, (for this to be a helpful hint) can you elaborate on how you would complete the solution?